# Best way to make a login page with HSQLDB - Java

Tags: java, authentication, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB (locally) in order to store and display some data in an application. Now, I want to create an administration app where I can manage these data. For this, I need a login page.

I was wondering what was the best way to do so? I noticed that HSQL is using a login system but I don't really know how it works. Is it meaningful to use it or rather make a custom login system by creating a table in the database and checking-in when the user is logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HSQLDB there are database USERs that can have different ROLEs. Each USER or ROLE can have its own level of privileges. See the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/accesscontrol-chapt.html

It is a good idea to use the USER with the DBA role solely for admin tasks. For general application access, you should create a USER and grant it a different ROLE without the DBA privileges.

As each USER has its own password, the password for admin USER should be different from the non-admin USER.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only thing that I didn't found in the doc was how to check if the username/password match a registered user? Is there any table with all the informations?

Comment: Check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables. You cannot find the password as it is stored as a hash.

Comment: Yes but I can compare the two passwords by passing the clear password into the hashing method? If it exists.

Comment: You cannot access the password at all.

Comment: If you want to limit access to the admin page itself with a username and password, you can store this in one of your tables in the database. The access control for database admin is a separate issue and controlled by the database.

Comment: oh ok that's what I thought. Thanks for clearing things up!